# Phaser 3 how to vertically align canvas

Tags: javascript, html, css, phaser-framework, game-development

I want to resize and center my canvas by horizontally and vertically. I found several solutions but none of them works for vertical alignment. I use this example:

```
function resize() {
  let canvas = document.querySelector("canvas");
  canvas.style.display = "block";
  let width = window.innerWidth;
  let height = window.innerHeight;
  let wratio = width / height;
  let ratio = config.width / config.height;
  if (wratio < ratio) {
    canvas.style.width = width + "px";
    canvas.style.height = (width / ratio) + "px";
  } else {
    canvas.style.width = (height * ratio) + "px";
    canvas.style.height = height + "px";
  };
  canvas.style.margin = "auto";
  canvas.style.padding = "0";
}
```

This code perfectly resized and centered canvas by horizontally, but none of the changes make the same thing for vertical alignment it sticks to the top of my browser (chrome). Who can help? Thank you a lot for your answers.

Answer (score 0):

You could use a container as a flexbox and then use `justify-content` to align them horizontally, and `align-items` to align them vertically on the container, or you use `align-self` on the canvas to align it vertically.

you can read more about [Flexbox here](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/)

```css
.flexcontainer{
  width:100vw;
  height: 100vh;
  background:orange;
  /*Flex-Container*/
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  /*align-items: center;*/
  
}
.can{
  align-self:center;
  width:50vw;
  height: 50vh;
  background:red;
}
```

```html
<div class="flexcontainer">
  <canvas class="can"></canvas>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively, pop it into the body tag if you have one.

```html
  <body style="display:flex;justify-content:center;align-items:center;">
      <div id="game"></div>
  </body>
```